# Using jquery to use ajax, POST, json. I get success but POST does not appear to run

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am getting the success alert but the function that updates the date does not run. What am I missing. This is my first time trying this.  Both the acquireddate and DefendantID have values.

This is the code on the aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("[id*=textboxAcquiredDate]").change(function () {
            var AcquiredDate = $(this).val();
            var DefendantID = $(this).attr("DefendantID");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Defendants.aspx/acquireddate_update",
                    data: "{'DefendantID' : '" + DefendantID + "', 'AcquiredDate' : '" + AcquiredDate + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("error.");
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("update successful.");
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is the code in the aspx.vb file (this function is not running):

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod()>
Public Shared Sub acquireddate_update(DefendantID, AcquiredDate)

    Dim stringCommand As String = "UPDATE dbo.Defendant SET AcquiredDate=@AcquiredDate WHERE DefendantID=@DefendantID;"
    Using con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionstringdev").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(stringCommand, con)
        cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@DefendantID", DefendantID)
            .AddWithValue("@AcquiredDate", AcquiredDate)
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: put a break in the webmethod and see if it gets hit in debug

Comment: I tried that. I got no hit in debug.

Comment: <ScriptMethod()>  cannot be used with a POST

Comment: Are you saying I should remove <ScriptMethod()>

Comment: I modeled this code from a sample from aspsnippets: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Update-Data-to-Database-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-WebMethod-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I just copied and pasted this sample: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx  and onsuccess alert(response.d) the response.d is undefined

Comment: I believe the issue is authentication.  using the browser debug and Network I see the message Authentication failed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the RouteConfig.vb file I commented out this line:

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent

Now it is working!